# powershell csom to update document library field value

Tags: powershell

I have a document library with name Project and it has 5000 records. I have one field business(choice field). I want to run powershell csom on this particular document library and update the value of business field from IBG to IBL where ever it has.

This is o365 so need powershell csom. Can someone provide me script please.

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
$siteurl = "SiteURL"  
Connect-SPOnline -Url $siteurl  
$ctx = Get-SPOContext
$listItems = Get-SPOListItem -List PnPList -Query "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='BusinessField'/><Value Type='Text'>IBG</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
foreach($item in $listItems)
{
    Set-SPOListItem -List "PnPList" -Identity $item -Values @{"BusinessField"="IBL";"ProductId"="6"}  
}
```

Comment: Is this the complete script or do I need to update anything in this?

Comment: Just validate the field names and values. Rest everything is fine